# `try` method when trying to fetch hash value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to avoid an error message when pulling from a hash which may or may not have a value.  I either want it to return the value or return nil.

I thought the `try` method would do it, but I'm still getting an error.

```
key not found: "en"
```

My hash is an hstore column called `content`... `content['en']`, etc.

```
content = {"es"=>"This is an amazing event!!!!!", "pl"=>"Gonna be crap!"}
```

Try method

```
@object.content.try(:fetch, 'en') # should return nil, but errors even with try method
```

I thought this would work but it doesn't. How else can I return a `nil` instead of an error?

Also, the content field itself might also be `nil` so calling `content['en']` throws:

```
undefined method `content' for nil:NilClass
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you need to allow for `object.content.nil?`, then you'd use `try`. If you want to allow for a missing key then you don't want `fetch` (as [Priti notes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17382581/479863)), you want the normal `[]` method. Combining the two yields:

```
object.content.try(:[], 'en')
```

Observe:

```
> h = { :a => :b }
 => {:a=>:b} 
> h.try(:[], :a)
 => :b 
> h.try(:[], :c)
 => nil 
> h = nil
 => nil 
> h.try(:[], :a)
 => nil
```

You could also use `object.content.try(:fetch, 'en', nil)` if `:[]` looks like it is mocking you.

Comment: *You could also use `object.content.try(:fetch, 'en', nil)` if `:[]` looks like it is mocking you.* - I like your this statement.. `Hash#fetch`, my favourite method.. :))

Answer (score 12):

See the [Hash#fetch](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html#method-i-fetch)

> Returns a value from the hash for the given key. If the key can’t be found, there are several options: With no other arguments, ***it will raise an KeyError exception***; if default is given, then that will be returned; if the optional code block is specified, then that will be run and its result returned.

```
h = { "a" => 100, "b" => 200 }
h.fetch("z")
# ~> -:17:in `fetch': key not found: "z" (KeyError)
```

So use:

```
h = { "a" => 100, "b" => 200 }
h.fetch("z",nil)
# => nil
h.fetch("a",nil)
# => 100
```

Comment: +1 `h.fetch('z', nil)` would be the non exception throwing version then.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I was late to update that here.. as my editor got hanged.. :((

Comment: Fetch is great until the object you're calling on is nil.

Comment: @jmoon90 - that's true for all great function (-`

Answer (score 3):

Just use normal indexing:

```
content['en'] #=> nil
```

Comment: woops, i forgot one important detail in my question. if content itself is nil content['en'] will throw an undefined method error.

Comment: not at all, your answer helped improve my question and get the answer i needed! Thanks

Comment: @holden" Good. Glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

As of Ruby 2.0, using `try` on a possibly `nil` hash is not neat. You can use `NilClass#to_h`. And for returning `nil` when there is no key, that is exactly what `[]` is for, as opposed to what `fetch` is for.

```
@object.content.to_h["en"]
```